# using Set in a Svelte Custom Store with multiple variables

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

when I use the update method, everything works fine but im trying to understand the set method for when a store is like this. What is the correct way?

```
export const todoStore = (() => {
    const { subscribe, update, set } = writable({
        allTask: [],
        isLoading: false,
    });

    return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        set,

        get: async () => {
            try {
                let { data, error } = await supabase.from('list').select('*');

                // method 1 using update words
                 update((state) => {
                     state.allTask = data;
                     return state;
                 });

                // method 2 using set doesn't work
                todoStore.set({
                    allTask: data
                });

                if (error) throw error;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like with `update()` call `set()` directly - with this you call the destructured methods from the writable store at the beginning `const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(...)`

On the return object this

```
return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        set,
        ...
}
```

is a shorthand for this

```
return {
        subscribe: subscribe,
        update: update,
        set: set,
        ...
}
```

while the values are references to the same destructured methods, so they can be called from ***outside*** on the store with `todoStore.set()` / `todoStore.update()`
If you want to prevent that the store is changed from the outside, you can remove `update` and `set` from the return object and only call them from inside the store scope